# What is this big Black Mass in Syria, as seen on google maps?

Tags: volcanology, desert

What is this [big black dot](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/33%C2%B002'02.8%22N+37%C2%B012'09.6%22E/@32.9948571,37.0567835,58105m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d33.0341008!4d37.2026555) on the satellite view of google maps, located in Syria at about 4:00 from Damascus?

[image: Big Black dot in Syria]

Comment: @njuffa - yes, kind of. But that question is very, very broad in its title so it didn't turn up in any of my searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Al-Safa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Safa_(Syria)) Volcano in Syria. According to Wikipedia it last erupted in 1850 AD.